# Create a EJB 3.0 project in eclipse with OC4J 10.1.3

Tags: eclipse, ejb-3.0, oc4j

I'm trying to create a new EJB 3.0 project on eclipse and I want to run it into the OC4J oracle server. Under JDeveloper I can use EJBs 3.0 because it is prepared, but eclipse is not allowing me to create any project further from EJBs 2.1.

Any idea of how to bypass this or how to trick it? If the server is able to run the project, I shouldn't have any problem...

thanks in advance!!

[My problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blSVO.png)

Answer (score 0):

OC4J development has ceased and all Eclipse tooling has been removed in Kepler release. You can target a different server in Eclipse, then export your app archives and manually deploy to OC4J, but you should really be planning on migrating to Oracle WebLogic Server.